# Putting images (emoticons) on ListView

Tags: android, xml, listview, emoticons

I want to add new functionality to my chat. I have a code that allows me to insert chat bubbles and it's working pretty fine ([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOb9i.png),[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8uRZ.png)). I tried to make message and adapter (for images) classes analogically to previous adapter and message (for text) classes. I want it to work less like Messenger. When the message box is empty, sending button is emoticon button and it should put an emoticon on ListView (I skip increasing emoticon size within the length of pressing). When message box has text, emoticon button will change to sending button and this button should put the content of the box on the ListView. I tried but everything I tried, failed (when I put setAdapter to TextChangedListener the button do nothing and when I set setAdapter strictly to emojiAdapter Android Studio will throw me Null Pointer Exception). Below is my code:

Error log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.bk.cryptit, PID: 2720
              java.lang.NullPointerException
                  at com.bk.cryptit.Chats.sendEmojiMessage(Chats.java:115)
                  at com.bk.cryptit.Chats$2.onClick(Chats.java:77)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Application terminated.
```

ChatMessage.java

```
package com.bk.cryptit;

import java.util.Random;

public class ChatMessage {

public String body, sender, receiver, senderName;
public String Date, Time;
public String msgid;
public boolean isMine;

public ChatMessage(String Sender, String Receiver, String messageString,
                   String ID, boolean isMINE) {
    body = messageString;
    isMine = isMINE;
    sender = Sender;
    msgid = ID;
    receiver = Receiver;
    senderName = sender;
}

public void setMsgID() {

    msgid += "-" + String.format("%02d", new Random().nextInt(100));
    ;
}
}
```

ChatAdapter.java

```
package com.bk.cryptit;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import static android.R.id.list;

public class ChatAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
ArrayList<ChatMessage> chatMessageList;

public ChatAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<ChatMessage> list) {
    chatMessageList = list;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return chatMessageList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ChatMessage message = (ChatMessage) chatMessageList.get(position);
    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chatbubble, null);

    TextView msg = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
    msg.setText(message.body);
    msg.setTextSize(16);
    msg.setSingleLine(false);
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) vi
            .findViewById(R.id.bubble_layout);
    LinearLayout parent_layout = (LinearLayout) vi
            .findViewById(R.id.bubble_layout_parent);
    layout.setPadding(15,11,15,15);

    // if message is mine then align to right
    if (message.isMine) {
        layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.chat_bubble_right);
        parent_layout.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
    }
    // If not mine then align to left
    else {
        layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.chat_bubble_left);
        parent_layout.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
    }
    if (message.isMine) {
        msg.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

    else {
        msg.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    }

    return vi;
}

public void add(ChatMessage object) {
    chatMessageList.add(object);
}
}
```

EmojiMessage.java

```
package com.bk.cryptit;

import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.Random;

public class EmojiMessage {
public String sender, receiver, senderName;
public ImageView body;
public String Date, Time;
public String msgid;
public boolean isMine;// Did I send the message.

public EmojiMessage(String Sender, String Receiver, ImageView emoji,
                   String ID, boolean isMINE) {
    body = emoji;
    isMine = isMINE;
    sender = Sender;
    msgid = ID;
    receiver = Receiver;
    senderName = sender;
}
public void setMsgID() {

    msgid += "-" + String.format("%02d", new Random().nextInt(100));
    ;
}
}
```

EmojiAdapter.java

```
package com.bk.cryptit;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class EmojiAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
ArrayList<EmojiMessage> chatMessageListEmoji;

public EmojiAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<EmojiMessage> list) {
    chatMessageListEmoji = list;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return chatMessageListEmoji.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    EmojiMessage message = (EmojiMessage) chatMessageListEmoji.get(position);
    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.imagechatbubble, null);

    ImageView msgEmoji = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.message_image);
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) vi
            .findViewById(R.id.bubble_layout);
    LinearLayout parent_layout = (LinearLayout) vi
            .findViewById(R.id.bubble_layout_parent);

    // if message is mine then align to right
    if (message.isMine) {
        parent_layout.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
    }
    // If not mine then align to left
    else {
        parent_layout.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
    }

    return vi;
}

public void add(EmojiMessage object) {
    chatMessageListEmoji.add(object);
}
}
```

Chats.java

```
package com.bk.cryptit;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.bk.cryptit.ChatAdapter;
import com.bk.cryptit.ChatMessage;
import com.bk.cryptit.CommonMethods;
import com.bk.cryptit.EmojiMessage;
import com.bk.cryptit.EmojiAdapter;
import com.bk.cryptit.R;

public class Chats extends Fragment {

private EditText msg_edittext;
private String user1 = "khushi", user2 = "khushi1";
private Random random;
public static ArrayList<ChatMessage> chatlist;
public static ArrayList<EmojiMessage> emojilist;
public static EmojiAdapter emojiAdapter;
public static ChatAdapter chatAdapter;
ListView msgListView;
String editText;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_welcome, container, false);
    random = new Random();
    msg_edittext = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    msgListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.messegesListView);
    editText = msg_edittext.getText().toString();
    final ImageButton sendButton = (ImageButton) view
            .findViewById(R.id.button10);
    sendButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.like);
    // ----Set autoscroll of listview when a new message arrives----//
    msgListView.setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
    msgListView.setStackFromBottom(true);

    chatlist = new ArrayList<ChatMessage>();
    chatAdapter = new ChatAdapter(getActivity(), chatlist);
    emojilist = new ArrayList<EmojiMessage>();
    emojiAdapter = new EmojiAdapter(getActivity(), emojilist);

    msg_edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            if (msg_edittext.getText().length()>0) {
                sendButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.sending_black);
                msgListView.setAdapter(chatAdapter);
            } else sendButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.like); msgListView.setAdapter(emojiAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (msg_edittext.getText().length()>0) {
                sendButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.sending_black);
                msgListView.setAdapter(chatAdapter);
            } else sendButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.like); msgListView.setAdapter(emojiAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (msg_edittext.getText().length()>0) {
                sendButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.sending_black);
                msgListView.setAdapter(chatAdapter);
            } else sendButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.like); msgListView.setAdapter(emojiAdapter);
        }
    });
    sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sendTextMessage(v);
        }
    });




    return view;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
}

public void sendTextMessage(View v) {
    String message = msg_edittext.getEditableText().toString();
    if (!message.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        final ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage(user1, user2,
                message, "" + random.nextInt(1000), true);
        chatMessage.setMsgID();
        chatMessage.body = message;
        chatMessage.Date = CommonMethods.getCurrentDate();
        chatMessage.Time = CommonMethods.getCurrentTime();
        msg_edittext.setText("");
        chatAdapter.add(chatMessage);
        chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
public void sendEmojiMessage(View v) {
    String message = msg_edittext.getEditableText().toString();
    android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView emoji = (android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.message_image);
    emoji.setImageResource(R.drawable.like);
    if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        final EmojiMessage emojiMessage = new EmojiMessage(user1, user2, emoji, "" + random.nextInt(1000), true);
        emojiMessage.body = emoji;
        emojiMessage.Date = CommonMethods.getCurrentDate();
        emojiMessage.Time = CommonMethods.getCurrentTime();
        msg_edittext.setText("");
        emojiAdapter.add(emojiMessage);
        emojiAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
}
```

chatbubble.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/imagebubble_layout_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/imagebubble_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="56dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
        android:id="@+id/message_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/like"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

imagechatbubble.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/imagebubble_layout_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/imagebubble_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="56dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
        android:id="@+id/message_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/like"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do you know what a NullPointerException is? at com.bk.cryptit.Chats.sendEmojiMessage(Chats.java:115)
                  at com.bk.cryptit.Chats$2.onClick(Chats.java:77) --> these are where you errors are happening. you are returning something that is null

Comment: is line 115 this? android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView emoji = (android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.message_image); Why is this not a ImageView but you have a android.support.v7.widget.....etc

Comment: Because to display vector image in pre lollipop android I need to use AppCompat.

Comment: you sure? https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html

Comment: Strange thing. Because when I used ImageView in android 4.4.4 vector underwent rasterization before it got displayed

Answer (score 0):

First, we need to test emoji is easily send to listView which has text above it.
You may add interface in activity which calls from the adapter. 
The interface will call the TextChangedListener which eventually display send button or emoji.